# spring controller: accept date / time in many different formats

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, date-formatting

in my controller i need to support many different date formats, like:

```
2018-08-24 13:00
2018-08-24
2009-12-31 23:59:59.999 +0100
2019-04-08T16:01:09
```

can i just create a pojo used by controller and somehow tell spring to support multiple formats?

```
data class UserRequest(
        @field:DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) // more formats?
        val start: LocalDateTime,
        // ... other fields
)

@RestController
class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/xxx")
    fun get(request: UserRequest) = ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ConversionService` for it, here is an example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters

Comment: thx, but it shows how to set only one format, not multiple different formats

Comment: How about implementing your own converter, where you have freedom to parse dates as you want? here is another example:https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder

Answer (score -1):

Why you specify a format ?
Dont use LocalDateTime , but DateTime or JodaTime .